# Is there a way to add shred to right-click menu?

Tags: nautilus, menu, delete, bleachbit, shredding

BleachBit lets you shred either folders or files if you use the menu from within the program but is it possible to add a shred option to the menu when you right click on a file or folder that you may want to delete?

I didn't see anything from within BleachBit preferences. It would be great to have this option beside the move to rubbish bin in the menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to shred file or folder you can use 
[nautilus-wipe](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-wipe/) [image: Install nautilus-wipe] .
It is a nautilus extension that adds shredding data options in nautilus right-click menu.

- You can add it to you nautilus using `sudo apt-get install nautilus-wipe`.
- Now restart your nautilus using `nautilus -q` and then starting it either opening it from Dash or using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `nautilus`.
- Now you can find a **wipe** option in nautilus right click menu.

[image]

- Selecting this option will open a pop-up window (with some additional option).

  [image]
- Click on OK to wipe you data completely.

Other option is by adding `shred` in nautilus right click menu.
  [Here](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/09/delete-files-securely-in-nautilus-linux.html) is a great article on it.